# SQL join with projection count on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to wrap my head around the SQL query that spans 2 tables. I haven't found my way around.

customer:

```
| id| firstname | lastname | email   | customertype | state  |
| 1 | joe       | doe      | joe@doe | walk in      | active |
| 2 | foo       | bar      | foo@bar | contractor   | active |
```

order:

```
| id| customerid | itemname  | itemtype | cost   | date
| 1 | 2          | pull      | t1       | 2.99   | 2018-07-24
| 2 | 1          | push      | t3       | 0.99   | 2018-06-01
| 3 | 2          | push      | t3       | 0.99   | 2018-05-13
```

the idea is to count how many of each item type, users of certain types, say `contractar` has ordered.

only 3 types of items are stocked: `t1,t2,t3`. so I need to project the count of the types as follows:

```
| customerid | firstname | lastname | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| 2          | foo       | bar      | 1  | 0  | 1  |

select customerid,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       t1 = (select count(t1) from order where item type = t1),
       t2 = (select count(t2) from order where item type = t2),
       t3 = (select count(t3) from order where item type = t3),
       from order join customer on order.customerid = customer.id
       where customer.customertype = 'contractor' and date > dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
```

Comment: did you get any exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of issue in you query is, you are not filtering orders by customer in `Select` subqueries.

```
t1 = (select count(t1) from order where item type = t1), -- missing filter on customerid, 
--so you will get count t1 orders for all customer. Same count for all customers.
```

Either you can modify your query to have customer filter or you can use aggregate function `SUM` with `CASE` condition by grouping customer, like below -

```
select customerid,
   firstname,
   lastname,
   SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 't1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as t1
   SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 't2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as t2
   SUM(CASE WHEN item_type = 't3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as t3
from order 
   join customer on order.customerid = customer.id
where customer.customertype = 'contractor' 
   and date > dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
Group by customerid, firstname,lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIVOT` you can try below code:

```
DECLARE @Customer AS TABLE
    (
        Id INT ,
        FirstName VARCHAR(100) ,
        Lastname VARCHAR(100) ,
        email NVARCHAR(100) ,
        CustomerType VARCHAR(100) ,
        [State] VARCHAR(10)
    );

DECLARE @Order AS TABLE
    (
        Id INT ,
        CustomerId INT ,
        ItemName VARCHAR(100) ,
        ItemType CHAR(2) ,
        Cost DECIMAL(10, 2) ,
        [Date] DATE
    );

INSERT INTO @Customer ( Id ,
                        FirstName ,
                        Lastname ,
                        email ,
                        CustomerType ,
                        State )
VALUES ( 1 ,             -- Id - int
         'joe' ,         -- FirstName - varchar(100)
         'doe' ,         -- Lastname - varchar(100)
         N'asdas@asdf' , -- email - nvarchar(100)
         'walk in' ,     -- CustomerType - varchar(100)
         'active'        -- State - varchar(10)
    ) ,
       ( 2 ,             -- Id - int
         'foo' ,         -- FirstName - varchar(100)
         'bar' ,         -- Lastname - varchar(100)
         N'asdas@dgdf' , -- email - nvarchar(100)
         'contractor' ,  -- CustomerType - varchar(100)
         'active'        -- State - varchar(10)
       );


INSERT INTO @Order ( Id ,
                     CustomerId ,
                     ItemName ,
                     ItemType ,
                     Cost ,
                     Date )
VALUES ( 1 ,        -- Id - int
         2 ,        -- CustomerId - int
         'pull' ,   -- ItemName - varchar(100)
         't1' ,     -- ItemType - char(2)
         2.99 ,     -- Cost - decimal(10, 2)
         '20180724' -- Date - date
    ) ,
       ( 2 ,        -- Id - int
         1 ,        -- CustomerId - int
         'push' ,   -- ItemName - varchar(100)
         't3' ,     -- ItemType - char(2)
         0.99 ,     -- Cost - decimal(10, 2)
         '20180601' -- Date - date
       ) ,
       ( 3 ,        -- Id - int
         2 ,        -- CustomerId - int
         'push' ,   -- ItemName - varchar(100)
         't3' ,     -- ItemType - char(2)
         0.99 ,     -- Cost - decimal(10, 2)
         '20180513' -- Date - date
       );




SELECT *
FROM   (   SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId ,
                  c.FirstName ,
                  c.Lastname ,
                  o.Id ,
                  o.ItemType
           FROM   @Customer c
                  JOIN @Order o ON c.Id = o.CustomerId
           WHERE  c.CustomerType = 'contractor' -- your filter for customer type
                  AND o.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) -- your date filter
) src
PIVOT (   COUNT(Id)
          FOR ItemType IN ( [t1], [t2], [t3] )) piv;
```